# is it possible to replace Application.java with Application.groovy?

Tags: groovy, spring-boot

I'm trying to build an executable jar using spring boot and groovy.

Is it possible to replace Application.java with Application.groovy?   I can only find examples of the main class written in java.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically just add the `org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all` dependency to your build.gradle file and also add `apply plugin: 'groovy'` and it should pick up your groovy files.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

This example application shows you how create an entirely groovy based spring boot executable jar: https://github.com/philwebb/SpringMvcGroovy